# Ubuntu 14.04 battery indicator showing status of the mouse battery

Tags: 14.04, unity, power-management, indicator, battery

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 64-bit and the battery indicator always shows the status of the mouse battery when my laptop is plugged in. I tried every setting possible and even re-plugged the nano receiver for the mouse, but it did not resolve this issue. Note that when the computer is running on battery power the status of the laptop battery is displayed. However, I want the battery status of the internal laptop battery to be displayed regardless of the fact that a mouse is attached or the laptop battery is charging. How can I do so, is there an **alternative battery indicator** on Ubuntu?

The screenshots depicting the issue is below:

[image]

[image]

[image]